# SharePoint 2013 hide ellipses menu

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

How can I hide the ellipses menu on SharePoint 2013 sites, documents and libraries?

thanks

Nate

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check user permssion. For more information, you can refer to:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/678653/How-to-check-user-permission-for-the-web-list-or-S

http://blog.fidelityfactory.com/2011/11/29/sharepoint-client-ecma-script-check-user-permissions/

Then if the user has the read only permission, you can use the code below to hide the ellipses menu in document library.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

$(document).ready(function () {

                $('.ms-listviewtable tr').find('td:eq(3),th:eq(3)').remove();


    });

You need to change the class name of your table.

more information refer to : http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-remove-table-column-by-column-number/

(thanks to Linda Li the issue was resolved).

I have written following code for checking permissions and hiding the ellipses if the loggedin user has read only privilages.

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
var clientContext;
var website;
$(document).ready(function () {
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    website = clientContext.get_web();
    clientContext.load(website);
    var ob = new SP.BasePermissions();  
    ob.set(SP.PermissionKind.addListItems)
    ob.set(SP.PermissionKind.managePermissions)

    var per = website.doesUserHavePermissions(ob)
    if (per.get_value())
    {
        $('.ms-listviewtable tr').find('td:eq(3),th:eq(3)').show();
    }
    else
    {
            $('.ms-listviewtable tr').find('td:eq(3),th:eq(3)').hide();
    }
});
```